# RxJava2: execute an async function for every item in a list and wait for callback

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm struggling with RxJava2. I want to perform a function on each item of a list. This function :

```
public void function(final Result result) {

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(result.getId()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            // do some operation
        }
    });
}
```

This function is async and use FirebaseFirestore.

So I tried to use RxJava2 on my list to call the function for every item:

```
Observable.fromIterable(resultList)
                    .concatMap(result -> Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call() throws Exception {
                            function(result);
                            return "ok";
                        }
                    }))
                    .subscribe(r -> {
                        // do some operation when all firebase async tasks are done
                    });
```

The concatMap works and the function is called for every item of the list. The problem is that I need a callback when all firebase async tasks are done.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: any feedback from the suggested solution below?

Comment: @AnthonyFillion-Maillet: When all tasks are done onComplete should be called?

Comment: @Lino Thank you for your answer, I tried it but unfortunately it seems like onComplete is not called

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh yes exactly

Comment: @AnthonyFillion-Maillet make sense. I updated the answer trying to embed into a custom object the information related to the last request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to draw a possible solution:

```
public class Callback implements OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
     private final ObservableEmitter<DocumentSnapshot> emitter;
     private final boolean last;

     public Callback(boolean lastvalue, ObservableEmitter<DocumentSnapshot> e) {
        this.last = lastvalue;
        this.emitter = e;
     }

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot value) {
         emitter.onNext(value);
         if (last) {
             emitter.onComplete();
         }
     }
}


Observable<DocumentSnapshot> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<DocumentSnapshot> e) throws Exception {
            int i = 1;
            for (Result result : resultList) {
                /* callback object now knows which is the last request so it can emit the onComplete */
                Callback callbackInstance = new Callback(resultList.size() == i, e);
                i++;
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                            .document(result.getId()).get().addOnSuccessListener(callbackInstance);
                }
            }
        });
```

then when the subscriber's `onComplete` action is hit all the requests to Firebase should be completed.